# ListBox inside ListBox, how do I know which button is clicked?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have two ListBoxes, one inside another.  And both ListBoxes will have items dynamically added into them upon user request.

Each time a button (not shown in the below code snippet) is clicked, a new item is added to the listbox. Each new item includes a new listbox and others.

And I have buttons inside the inner listbox, one for each list item of the inner listbox.

With `DataContext`, I can find the data binded to the inner list item, and make changes to it, so that changes are reflected on the proper list item.

However, I also need to make changes to the data binded to the outer list item, which corresponds to the button. How can I know which one it is?

I have came up with a solution, which I believe it not elegant enough. By making changes to the model, I can have each inner data holds a reference to the outer data, so that I can find the data binded to the outer list item. This doesn't seem like a proper solution though.  Do you have any suggestions?

---

Below is code snippet of the xaml.  I've simplified it, hope it's easy to understand.  I feel you don't have to read the whole code.

```
<ListBox Name="QuestionsListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItem}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Question, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <ListBox Name="ChoicesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Click="ChoiceAddButton_Click" Height="72" Width="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/choices.add.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-20,0" />
            </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you just need a reference to the `DataContext` of the outer `ListBox` that you can use in `ChoiceAddButton_Click`, or is it something more complex?

Comment: @Esoteric Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `QuestionsListBox.DataContext` inside `ChoiceAddButton_Click` directly? You have a direct way to reference the outer `ListBox` from your code behind since you've given it a name, and `DataContext` is an accessible property.

```
    private void ChoiceAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        var outerLBDataContext= QuestionsListBox.DataContext;
        ...
    }
```

This works fine for me in a demo solution using your provided XAML.

**Edit 2:**

Sorry, wasn't thinking. The `Button`'s `DataContext` will be a `Choice`, not the `Choices` collection.

Your inner `ListBox`'s `DataContext` is *not* a `Question`, it's `Choices`. Your outer `TextBox` has `Question.Question` as its `DataContext`. Binding `Text` or `ItemsSource` makes the `DataContext` point to the binding target. Here is a bit of tricky XAML to sneak in a `DataContext` reference.

Add an `ElementName` to your outer `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Question, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" ElementName="questionTextBox"/>
```

Now, add a hidden TextBlock inside your inner `ListBox`:

```
    <ListBox Name="ChoicesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItem}"> 
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"> 
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> 
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Click="ChoiceAddButton_Click" Height="72" Width="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent"> 
                <Button.Background> 
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/choices.add.png" Stretch="Fill" /> 
                </Button.Background> 
            </Button> 
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-20,0" /> 
            <TextBlock Name="hiddenTextBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=questionTextBox, Path=DataContext}"
        </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate> 
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListBox>
```

Finally, inside your event handler, you can navigate around the tree to get that reference:

```
    private void ChoiceAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        if(btn == null) return; //won't happen when this method handles the event
        Grid g = btn.Parent as Grid;
        if(g!=null) // also unlikely to fail
        {
           TextBlock tb = g.FindName("hiddenTextBlock") as TextBlock;
           if(tb!=null) // also unlikely to fail, but never hurts to be cautious
           {
               var currentQuestion = tb.DataContext;
               // now you've got the DC you want
           }
        }
    }
```

I'd like to note that this isn't really an elegant solution. It is an all UI solution, however, which could be a useful thing. But better design would be to include `Parent` references in your `Choice` and `ChoiceList` (or whatever they're called) classes and use that. Then it would be as simple as calling `btn.DataContext.Parent.Parent` with appropriate type conversions. This way your code becomes easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Esoteric, this does not work for me. QuestionsListBox.DataContext returns null. What I need should be the `DataContext` of the relevant inner ListBox, not the outer ListBox. Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: How are you setting the `ItemsSource` of `QuestionsListBox`, and what type of object is it bound to? In my sample I bound it to an `ObservableCollection` in the constructor of my form, so I imagine you must be doing it differently. I'll edit my answer with a suggestion on how to get the `DataContext` of the inner `ListBox` (the one bound to `Choices`). You need that from inside `ChoiceAddButton_Click`, right?

Comment: I don't want the button's datacontext. That's a choice in my program. I don't want the outer list's itemsource. That's an observablecollection of questions. I want the inner list's datacontext, which should be a question.   I set the itemsource of the outer list to a collection of questions, itemsource of the inner one a collection of choices (which is a member of question).

Comment: You're right about the `DataContext` of the `Button`, sorry about that. I've updated my answer again, with another option which can be adapted to get whatever `DataContext` you need.

Comment: You finally got what I wanted. But sadly, we went back to the starting point. What you mentioned at the last part is the way I'm using now, as I wrote in the question.  Thank you very much for your spending so much time helping me!

Comment: I do think the way that you're using is the best way, but my answer does provide a method to do what you're asking using only view references, which you're free to use if you like. Just because I think something's a better design doesn't mean that you have to use it, or even that it is. Also, as long as you don't need your `Button`'s `DataContext` to point at the `Choice`, you could skip adding the hidden control and point the `Button`'s `DataContext` directly at `questionTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event to your inner model that your containing datamodel subscribes to before adding it to the 'Choices' collection and pass the relevant information that way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this necessary to use the Button control in your solution ??
If not fixed, then you can use the "Image control" as specified below `<Image Source="/Images/choices.add.png" Height="72" Width="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill"/>`

If you use the Image control then in combination with this you can add the selection changed event to inner list box ( ChoicesListBox). Then in the Handler you can get the item selected as it comes as parameter with the selection changed event(SelectionChangedEventArgs).

Modify the List box and add the Selection changed event handler as below

```
<ListBox Name="ChoicesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListItem}" SelectionChanged="Items_SelectionChanged">
```

in page.xaml.cs you can add the handler and access the item as follows

```
private void Items_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {           
            if (e.AddedItems[0] != null)
            {
//Please use the casting to the Choices items type to make use. 
                var temp = (ChoicesItemViewModel)e.AddedItems[0];
            }
    }
```